# Devise with CanCan(can)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan, cancancan

I can't seem to find a good tutorial for this and I've hit a bit of a wall.

I'm using rails 4.2.0 with a basic CRUD app. For auth I'm using devise and for roles I'm using Cancancan as these have fairly understandable documentation.

I have two types of Users:

Users and Admins.

Admins can interact with all models. Add-Edit-Delete etc.

Users can only interact with certain models. Which will be a booking system of sorts.

I'm not quite sure of the process I need to go through to set this up. Do I need to do a full rails generation for each user type or can I just use the Devise generation? Adding onto that how can I choose the user type? So far I have two login links which works.

The main issue I'm having is defining roles in cancancan.

Any help/questions on the subject would be appreciated.

Comment: For simplicity, you could add an `admin` boolean column on the users table. With cancancan, you would check for an admin user with `user.admin?`. https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities

Comment: As I have only used the 'rails g devise user' command so far I don't have anything similar to that. Does this mean I'll have to start again with a full rails generation of: 'rails g scaffold user' etc?

Comment: No, you can add additional columns to a table at any time with [migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html). I think my answer below should help get you started on implementing this. I suggest taking a read through the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). They are really extensive and will really help provide a nice foundation for you moving forward in Rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simplicity, you could add an `admin` boolean column on the users table. You would check for an admin user with `user.admin?`.

Here is what the migration will look like.

`> rails g migration add_admin_to_users`

In your migration file, I would set a default value to false prior to running it.

```
class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, null: false, default: false
  end

  def down
    remove_column :users, :admin
  end
end
```

By default, your users won't be admins. However, you can easily make a user an admin with `user.update_column(:admin, true)`.

With this, you should be able to follow the CanCanCan docs, as they are pretty extensive I believe.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new

    if user.admin?
      # admin abilities
    else
      # non-admin abilities
    end
  end
end
```

http://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities